# Nautilus Shell in TikZ or PSTricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Any ideas on how to recreate the cross-section of a nautilus shell like in the diagram below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is your MWE that shows your effort and difficulties?

Comment: @PGFTricks Thanks for the welcome!lol I have been participating in this site for more than a year so i kinda know the rules of TX.SX but I do agree i do not have a MWE. What I am looking for, is to learn the possible algorithm that could create such a diagram like the one you shared and the others as well. But thanks again for the concern.

Answer (score 10):

A --shell-output (it had to be done sorry)

Fibonacci approximation for the spiral. Complete guess at the color. Stealing Jake's `ncbar` (again!).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\tikzset{nctopath/.style={
     to path=(\tikztostart) ..controls ($(\tikztostart)!1cm*#1!-90:(\tikztotarget)$) and 
        ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!1cm*#1!-50:(\tikztotarget)$)!70:(\tikztostart)$).. 
    (\tikztotarget)
    },
}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\totx{1}
\coordinate (n-1-1) at (0,0) {};
\foreach \x[count=\xi from 2, evaluate=\x as \temptotx using int(\x+\totx)] in {1,...,9}{
\draw[decoration={
    markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.249 with {
            \coordinate (n-\x-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) ;
        }
   },postaction=decorate
] 
(n-\x-1) arc (\x*90+180:(\x+1)*90+180:{(\temptotx)*3mm}) 
coordinate (n-\xi-1) 
\pgfextra{\xdef\totx{\temptotx}};
}

\foreach \x[count=\xi from 5] in {1,...,4}{
    \foreach \y in {2,...,5}{
    \draw[ultra thick,draw=green!50,] (n-\x-\y) to[nctopath=\x] (n-\xi-\y);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needs a little make up though. Maybe shading those sections nicely and placing a fading in the middle of the shell for the sun flare etc.

Answer (score 8):

With PSTricks just for fun. The following is not the final.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{polarplot,algebraic}
\def\foo{2^(x/10)}
\def\goo#1{2 #1 10 div exp}

\def\hoo#1{%
    \pscurve
    (!\goo{#1 .4 add} \goo{#1 .4 add 2 Pi mul add} add 2 div #1 .4 add RadtoDeg PtoC)
    (!\goo{#1 .6 add 2 Pi mul add} #1 .6 add RadtoDeg PtoC)}

\def\atom#1{%
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange,linejoin=1]
    {
        \psplot{#1}{#1 .6 add}{\foo}
        \hoo{#1}
        \psplot{#1 .6 add 2 Pi mul add}{#1 2 Pi mul add}{\foo}
        \closepath
    }}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \foreach \i in {16,15.7,...,-55}{\atom\i}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hopefully the next edit will make it more realistic. But you should get the rough idea.

### How is it made?

The used algorithm is so simple as illustrated by the following animation.

[image]

Comment: It is actually used in the airport to transfer your baggage.

Comment: Yes, transfer your baggage down a deep, never-ending abyss.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you for upvoting. :-)

Comment: To reduce the file size, `plotpoints=10` is more than enough. The default is `plotpoints=50`.

Answer (score 8):

run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5.5,-6)(2,3)
\psset{viewpoint=20 120 60 rtp2xyz,Decran=20,lightsrc=-10 15 10}
% Parametric Surfaces
\psSolid[object=grille,base=-4 4 -4 4,action=draw*,linecolor={[cmyk]{1,0,1,0.5}}](0,0,-3)
\defFunction{shell}(u,v)
   {1.2 v exp u Sin dup mul v Cos mul mul}
   {1.2 v exp u Sin dup mul v Sin mul mul}
   {1.2 v exp u Sin u Cos mul mul}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,
   linecolor={[cmyk]{1,0,1,0.5}},
   base=0 pi pi 4 div neg 5 pi mul 2 div,
   fillcolor=yellow!50,incolor=green!50,
   function=shell,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,ngrid=25]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I think you need to cut it and show the cross section. :-)